# MessageComposeResult UIAlert Not showing

Tags: objective-c, sms, uialertview

I am trying to get an UIAlert that say, "message sent" when the user sends a text message. Here is what I have.

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController
                                      *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled)
    {
    }
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent)
    {
        UIAlertController* messageSent = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"Message Sent." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:NULL];
        [messageSent addAction:okAction];
        [self.presentViewController:messageSent animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Message failed");

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

When I run the app and send the message no UIAlert appears. Xcode also say, 
       Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used MFMessageComposeViewController but i think you have to first dismiss the MFMessageComposeViewController then show the alert in the completion like I've shown below. Try that and let me know if that works maybe self was referring to MFMessageComposeViewController? not sure about that!

```
else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent)
{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^{
        UIAlertController* messageSent = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"Message Sent." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:NULL];
        [messageSent addAction:okAction];
        [self presentViewController:messageSent animated:true completion:^{
            //try anything on completion
        }];
    }];
}
```